# FOSCommentBundle querybuilder add order make bad query?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, foscommentbundle

i have something strange in FOSCommentBundle

in FOS\CommentBundle\Entity\class CommentManager extends BaseCommentManager

method:

```
public function findCommentsByThread(ThreadInterface $thread, $depth = null, $sorterAlias = null)
```

queryBuilder:

```
$qb = $this->repository
                ->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->join('c.thread', 't')
                ->where('t.id = :thread')
                ->orderBy('c.ancestors', 'ASC')
                ->setParameter('thread', $thread->getId());

        if (null !== $depth && $depth >= 0) {
            // Queries for an additional level so templates can determine
            // if the final 'depth' layer has children.

            $qb->andWhere('c.depth < :depth')
               ->setParameter('depth', $depth + 1);
        }

        $comments = $qb
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();

        print_array([$qb->getQuery()->getSQL(),$comments]);
```

i get:

```
SELECT c0_.body AS body_0, c0_.ancestors AS ancestors_1, c0_.depth AS depth_2, c0_.created_at AS created_at_3, c0_.state AS state_4, c0_.id AS id_5, c0_.thread_id AS thread_id_6 FROM Comment c0_ INNER JOIN Thread t1_ ON c0_.thread_id = t1_.id WHERE t1_.id = ? ORDER BY c0_.ancestors ASC"
```

when i disable order

```
$qb = $this->repository
                    ->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->join('c.thread', 't')
                    ->where('t.id = :thread')
                    //->orderBy('c.ancestors', 'ASC')
                    ->setParameter('thread', $thread->getId());

            if (null !== $depth && $depth >= 0) {
                // Queries for an additional level so templates can determine
                // if the final 'depth' layer has children.

                $qb->andWhere('c.depth < :depth')
                   ->setParameter('depth', $depth + 1);
            }

            $comments = $qb
                ->getQuery()
                ->execute();

            print_array([$qb->getQuery()->getSQL(),$comments]);
```

i get:

```
SELECT c0_.body AS body_0, c0_.ancestors AS ancestors_1, c0_.depth AS depth_2, c0_.created_at AS created_at_3, c0_.state AS state_4, c0_.id AS id_5, c0_.score AS score_6, c0_.author_ip AS author_ip_7, c0_.author_name AS author_name_8, c0_.plus AS plus_9, c0_.minus AS minus_10, c0_.thread_id AS thread_id_11, c0_.author_id AS author_id_12 FROM Comment c0_ INNER JOIN Thread t1_ ON c0_.thread_id = t1_.id WHERE t1_.id = ?
```

here is entity:

```
<?php

namespace Place\PlaceBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\CommentBundle\Entity\Comment as BaseComment;
use FOS\CommentBundle\Model\VotableCommentInterface;
use FOS\CommentBundle\Model\SignedCommentInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\ChangeTrackingPolicy("DEFERRED_EXPLICIT")
     */
    class Comment extends BaseComment implements SignedCommentInterface, VotableCommentInterface
    {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Thread of this comment
     *
     * @var Thread
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Thread", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $thread;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    protected $score = 0;

    /**
     * Author of the comment
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Mea\ContactBundle\Entity\Contact")
     * @var User
     */
    protected $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
     * @var
     */
    protected $author_ip;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",nullable=true)
     * @var
     */
    protected $author_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $author_email;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    protected $plus=0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    protected $minus=0;


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPlus()
    {
        return $this->plus;
    }


    public function incrementPlus()
    {
        $this->plus += 1;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getMinus()
    {
        return $this->minus;
    }


    public function incrementMinus()
    {
        $this->minus += 1;
    }


    public function setAuthor(UserInterface $author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;
    }

    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function getAuthorName()
    {
        if (null === $this->getAuthor()) {
            if($this->author_name)
                return $this->author_name;
            else
                return 'Gość';
        }

        return $this->getAuthor()->getUsername();
    }


    /**
     * Sets the score of the comment.
     *
     * @param integer $score
     */
    public function setScore($score)
    {
        $this->score = $score;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current score of the comment.
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getScore()
    {
        return $this->score;
    }

    /**
     * Increments the comment score by the provided
     * value.
     *
     * @param integer value
     *
     * @return integer The new comment score
     */
    public function incrementScore($by = 1)
    {
        if($by>0)
            $this->incrementPlus();
        else $this->incrementMinus();

        $this->score += $by;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthorIp()
    {
        return $this->author_ip;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $author_ip
     */
    public function setAuthorIp($author_ip)
    {
        $this->author_ip = $author_ip;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $author_name
     */
    public function setAuthorName($author_name)
    {
        $this->author_name = $author_name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthorEmail()
    {
        return $this->author_email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $author_email
     */
    public function setAuthorEmail($author_email)
    {
        $this->author_email = $author_email;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $plus
     */
    public function setPlus($plus)
    {
        $this->plus = $plus;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $minus
     */
    public function setMinus($minus)
    {
        $this->minus = $minus;
    }

}
```

Anyone understand why add order create query without all fields ?